# wxFrame with Codeblock - unavailable blocks within second wxFrame

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxmathplot

I've got one question about wxSmith while worikng with CodeBlock.

I've create application that can do simple signal processing. For a while now, I've only been using only one wxFrame called "Naukaframe.wxs", and few mpWindow placed on it, however i needed to create another wxFrame called "Okno_startowe.wxs" with few seperated mpWindows on it.

While i was creating another wxFrame "Okno_startowe.wxs" I was not able to chose anything from Aui/Contrib/MathPlot tabs, however if i change back to main wxFrame, these tabs are still available.

Let me show you what i mean with pictures.

Here is main opened "Naukaframe.wxs"

[available objects](https://pasteboard.co/Ij3LWCR.png)

And here is second one created without available tabs.

[unavailable objects](https://pasteboard.co/Ij3uBv6.png)

I've tried to reincluding all of the files like mathplot.h, somehow still nothing changes. I expect to be able to use mpWindows (Mathplot in general) with every single wxFrame within my project.